# How to create a 32 bit red texture byte buffer

Tags: c++, image-processing, gdi+, directx-11

I want to make a red texture image buffer. Would anyone help me to make it in right way. I have tried following but could not copy the buffer into ID3D11Texture2D. I need help:

```
std::vector<BYTE> redTexture(w*h*4);
const auto stride = w * 4;
BYTE* buf = redTexture.data();

for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
{
    const auto redValue = Gdiplus::Color::Red;
    memcpy(buf, &redValue, stride);
    buf += stride;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `Graphics.FillRectangle(const Brush*, INT, INT, INT, INT)`?

Comment: I need to a byte buffer of red pixels of a texture that I have to copy into ID3D11Texture2D. Any other simple way to create?

Answer (score 0):

If the DXGI_FORMAT of your texture is R8G8B8A8_UNORM, you can do it like this;

```
std::vector<BYTE> redTexture(w*h*4);

for(int i=0; i<redTexture.size(); i++)
{
    if(i%4==0)
    {
        redTexture[i]=255;
    }
    else if(i%4==3)
    {
        redTexture[i]=255;
    }
    else
    {
        redTexture[i]=0;
    }
}
```

Since each pixel consists of RGBA 4 byte value, you should assign first and last bytes to 255, other bytes to 0 to get the red color.

Comment: My target texture is DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT

Comment: Though a solution is found. I would appreciate if someone posts a solution that does not require Gdiplus.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @HMD. I have solved the issue by doing the following:

```
    CImage m_cImage;
    // create a test image
    m_cImage.Create(w, -h, 8 * 4); // 8 bpp * 4 channel
    auto hdc = m_cImage.GetDC();
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc);

    // Create a SolidBrush object.
    Gdiplus::SolidBrush redBrush(Gdiplus::Color::Red);

    // Fill the rectangle.
    Gdiplus::Status status = graphics.FillRectangle(&redBrush, 0, 0, w, h);
    TRY_CONDITION(status == Gdiplus::Status::Ok);
    ....
    // Then saved the m_cImage.GetBits() to bmp file using Gdiplus::Bitmap
    // and my expected texture is found
```